# What Am I doing wrong with my number of elevators loop?

Tags: javascript

This is my column class where I call my number of elevators, on the second paragraph:

```
class Column {
constructor(floorsNumber, elevatorsNumber) {
    this.floorsNumber = floorsNumber;
    this.elevatorsNumber = elevatorsNumber;
    this.elevatorsList = [];
    this.directionButtonsList = [];
    
    // Number of elevators
    for (let i = 0; i < elevatorsNumber; i++) {
        this.elevatorsList.push(new Elevator(0, floorsNumber));
}



    for (let i = 0; i < this.floorsNumber; i++) {
        //  floor1 has no DOWN direction button
        if (i === 1) {
            this.directionButtonsList.push(new DirectionButton(i, "up", false));
        } 
        // floor10 has no UP direction button  
        else if (i === 10) {
            this.directionButtonsList.push(new DirectionButton(i, "down", false));
            
        }
         // The rest has both directions
        else {
            this.directionButtonsList.push(new DirectionButton(i, "up", false));
            this.directionButtonsList.push(new DirectionButton(i, "down", false));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I find the best elevator:

```
// Finding the best  elevator to answer the user's request
findElevator(requestedFloor, direction) {  
    var bestGap = this.floorsNumber;
    var bestElevator = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.elevatorsList.length; i++) { 
            // If the elevators and request's direction is moving UP and the requested floor is above the elevator
        if (this.elevatorsList[i].direction === "up" && direction === "up" && requestedFloor > this.elevatorsList[i].currentFloor) {
            bestElevator = this.elevatorsList[i];
        }   // If the elevators and request's direction is moving DOWN and the requested floor is under the elevator
        else if (this.elevatorsList[i].direction === "down" && direction === "down" && requestedFloor < this.elevatorsList[i].currentFloor) {
            bestElevator = this.elevatorsList[i]; 
                 //if elevator and request are descending and the request is below the elevator
        }   // If the elevator is idle
        else if (this.elevatorsList[i].status == "idle") {
            bestElevator = this.elevatorsList[i];
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.elevatorsList.length; i++) {
                // Absolute function is needed otherwise minus numbers would happen and the situation would be misinterpret
                let gap = Math.abs(this.elevatorsList[i].currentFloor - requestedFloor);
                if (gap < bestGap) {
                    bestElevator = this.elevatorsList[i];
                    bestGap = gap;   //Select the smallest gap to find the bestElevator
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("Best elevator is found on floor " + bestElevator.currentFloor);
    return bestElevator; 
}
```

Here is my scenario where I encounter a little problem, but I can't put my finger where I did wrong on my code above:
function Scenario1() {

```
columntest = new Column(10, 2);

columntest.elevatorsList[0].currentFloor = 2;
columntest.elevatorsList[0].direction = "";
columntest.elevatorsList[0].status = "idle";
columntest.elevatorsList[0].queue = [];

columntest.elevatorsList[1].currentFloor = 5;
columntest.elevatorsList[1].direction = "";
columntest.elevatorsList[1].status = "idle";
columntest.elevatorsList[1].queue = [];

columntest.requestElevator(1, "up");
```

}
Scenario1();`

My question is why the scenario is not the calling my elevator [0], instead of [1]. When 0 is obviously closer than elevator 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is because of this condition:

```
 else if (this.elevatorsList[i].status == "idle") {
            bestElevator = this.elevatorsList[i];
        }
```

For each iteration of the for loop the code will run through the if/else statements in order. So at i==0 the elevator isn't moving up, so that if condition is ignored. The elevator isn't moving down, so that else if condition is ignored. The elevator is idle, therefore that else if condition is run, and bestElevator is set to that index, and the for loop comparing distance isn't run.

I think if you want to check if there are moving elevators before calling idle ones, you'll have to run through the array completely looking for moving elevators, and if none is found then run a loop comparing the idle elevators.